# Undirected graph | Can robbers reach the magical exit or police catches them?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

In a given undirected graph, each vertex either has a `robber`, a `police`, empty vertex or a `magical exit`. Robbers and Police officers can move along edges of the graph with unit speed.

- If a robber reaches the magical exit, the robber is safe and police can't catch.
- If a police officer and a robber reach the same vertex, the police catches the robber.
- A police officer can't move to any magical exit.
- If a robber and police keep repeating the same pattern of movement on the graph, then it is a draw.
- The robber(s) and police(s) take turns strictly alternately starting with robber(s). At least 1 robber/police should move during the respective turn.
- Each robber and police plays optimally. After each move, the whole state of the graph is known to all the players to make the decision.

Given the initial position of R robbers, P police officers and M magical exits, one needs to answer if robbers win or police officers win or if it is a draw.

I am trying to figure out an algorithm that can help me with two variations:

- If each robber reaches any of the magical exits, robbers win. If every robber gets caught, police officers win. Otherwise, draw.
- If a single robber reaches any magical exit, robbers win. If a single robber gets caught, police officers win. Otherwise, draw.

Can robber(s) win?

I hope I was able to formulate the problem without any gaps. Though, feel free to clarify if you have any doubts. If you feel the urge to close this question as 'needs focus' because I have asked two variations, solve the first variation.

[image]

Comment: Can police/robbers choose not to move on specific occasions?

Comment: @SerialLazer Good question. It has been a tricky choice for me while formulating the problem whether no move should be allowed. Let us say no move is allowed. If neither robber(s) nor police(s) moves, it is a draw. If at least one robber or one police moves, the game continues.

Comment: How do they move? Like, do they take turns, or all the actors decide their next move simultaneously and then execute it simultaneously, or does it all happen in a continuous time?

Comment: Actually they all would mean the same. Correct me if wrong. In the above figure, the bottom robber won't move left because the bottom police would catch her, irrespective of how they move. But to keep the terms concrete let us say the robber(s) and police(s) take turns strictly alternately starting with robber(s). Now, no move is not an option then.

Comment: Does everyone know the graph beforehand or do they also have to discover as they move? Does each player know the positions of others after every move?

Comment: @ParthThakkar The graph and initial position of R robbers, P police officers and M magical exits are given as input. Every player knows the state of all other players all the time to make better decisions.

Comment: @SerialLazer Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

using BFS algorithm.

- moveCount= 0 while(queue is not empty) {moveCount++}
- object form {isPolice:bool, currentLocation, moveCount}
- start queue filled with the vertices of all polices and robbers like the above object form
- have arrays that store information like:
  canPoliceGetthere[location][moveCount](mark this array when you push it into que)
  safeRobbers[](add when you pop it)

I'm still thinking about repeating the same pattern, but I think it's not a problem. Using this way I think I can solve it.

Comment: Robber may follow the longest path to avoid the police officers in order to finally reach the magical exit. So, the straight forward BFS you mentioned would not work. If you still feel the above would work in all cases, it would be great if you code it so that I can test using different cases and possibly come up with counter examples.

Comment: I know.
object form modification:add number of the person.
I add all the next state of one person into queue and when I pop a object about the person. I don't remove other states of him so the BFS not returns the shortest path, but all the cases. I only remove the state when the robber will be catched by the police using canPoliceGetthere array

Comment: Thanks for posting your thought process. Though, I find it a bit difficult to follow it. It would be great if you could share a working code that I can test with different graph inputs. That would help me understand your approach and possibly find a counter example, if any

Comment: I'd like to know about the size of the graph, before I decide to code actually.

Comment: Consider max 50 vertices for now.